# Converting time zones in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have written a code which basically pulls out transactions from my DB in a PST time zone. What I'd like to do then is simply convert those dates into CEST time zone and IST (Israel Standard Time).

I did something like following :

```
  var transactions = ctx.UserStores.Where(x => x.UserId == loggedUser.UserId).SelectMany(x => x.StoreItems.SelectMany(y => y.StoreItemTransactions)).ToList();
                var hourlyData = transactions
                .GroupBy(x => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(x.TransactionDate.Value, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone)).Hour)
                .Select(pr => new HourlyGraph { Hour = pr.Key, Sales = pr.Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTransaction) })
                .ToList();
```

where timeZone parameter can be one of following:

```
Central European Standard Time

Israel Standard Time

Pacific Standard Time
```

Naurally when timeZone parameter is = PST  I would expect the same results in my list... But the weird thing is the results get completely shuffled up and I'm not sure why ...

So the dates in my DB are kept in PST time zone and I'm trying to convert them into one of these 3 above time zones...

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: What is the value of `x.TransactionDate.Value.Kind` and what time zone is the code running in? Have you tried using the version of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` that expects two `TimeZoneInformation`objects (source and target)

Comment: "the results get completely shuffled up" - what does that mean exactly? I'm unclear of exactly what your problem is. Are the results in the wrong order (is what I'd assume by shuffled)? Are the times incorrect? Something else? If you can give a minimal complete example of your problem then that would help greatly.

Comment: @NineBerry It says date time kind = System.DateTimeKind.Unspecified

Comment: @NineBerry I haven't used that, can you show me in example how to do it ?

Comment: @Chris I know for a fact results are stored in PST time zone. But when I pass parameter timezone=PST, the results are completely different. But they shouldn't be, they should be exactly the same as ones in DB =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code that uses the version of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` which expects both a source and target timezone.

```
DateTime sourceTime = new DateTime(2015, 6, 10, 10, 20, 30, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

foreach(var targetTimeZoneID in new string[] { "Pacific Standard Time", "Israel Standard Time", "Central European Standard Time" })
{
    TimeZoneInfo targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(targetTimeZoneID);
    var converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(sourceTime, sourceTimeZone, targetTimeZone);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", targetTimeZoneID, converted);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output is:

> Pacific Standard Time: 2015-06-10 10:20:30
>  Israel Standard Time:
>   2015-06-10 20:20:30
>  Central European Standard Time: 2015-06-10
>   19:20:30